# 3 is the magic number

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

I am wondering what is the answer to these if the magic number is 3. So like..

1 1 1=3
 2 2 2=3
 3 3 3=3
 4 4 4=3
 5 5 5=3
 6 6 6=3
 7 7 7=3
 8 8 8=3
 9 9 9=3
 10 10 10=3

Comment: I voted to close this question. As it stands the puzzle needs some clarification regarding what is allowed. I imagine answers like `|{X}|+|{X}|+|{X}|=3` are not intended.

Answer (score 2):

> $1 + 1 + 1=3$ 
>  
> $(2/ 2)+ 2=3$
>  
> $3+ 3- 3=3$
>  
> $4- 4 /4=3$
>  
> $\Big{\lceil}\sqrt[5]{ 5!+ 5}\Big{\rceil}=3$
>  
> $\Big{\lceil}\sqrt[6]{ 6!+ 6}\Big{\rceil}=3$ (It's amazing close, actually)
>  
> $\Big{\lfloor}\sqrt[7]{ 7!+ 7}\Big{\rfloor}=3$
>  
> $\Big{\lfloor}\sqrt[8]{ 8!+ 8}\Big{\rfloor}=3$
>  
> $\Big{\lfloor}\sqrt[9]{ 9! / 9}\Big{\rfloor}=3$
>  
> $\Big{\lfloor}\sqrt[10]{ 10! / 10}\Big{\rfloor}=3$

And the general formula,

> $\Big{(}\frac{d}{dx}n\Big{)}!+\Big{(} \frac{d}{dx}n \Big{)}!+ \Big{(}\frac{d}{dx}n \Big{)}!= 3$

Comment: (I've edited your answer to remove extraneous $\mathrm{d}x$s. Those are used in integrals, not derivatives.)